# Responsive design media queries not showing on apple products?

Tags: css, responsive-design, media-queries

I have a Ruby on Rails app developed with bootstrap and have included media queries in my 'static_pages.css.scss' file:

```
@media all and (max-width: 1000px){
    .header-logos
    {
       display: none;
    }
}
```

There is more code within the @media queries but just keeping this short.

I have also included:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
```

The responsive design works on my desktop as well as my nexus android device in chrome. I have also tested it on a samsung galaxy and it works fine.

If I load the website on an iphone or ipad (safari or chrome) the menue loads correctly but the rest of the screen goes blank (seems to flash for a second the correct display then goes blank)

Feel free to see the result by going to [www.bathtub2boardroom.com](http://www.bathtub2boardroom.com)

Any advice?

Comment: sorry to inform you but your responsive layout doesnt quite work on desktop (320px x 480px), but thats me being picky i guess, why are you using user-scalable=no ? remove it and see what happens

Comment: oh and shouldnt initial scale be 1.0 not 1 ? not sure if that makes a difference

Comment: Thanks for feedback @Richlewis :) please do be picky! I have now gone with your advice and currently looking for apple products to test!

Comment: The Bootstrap viewport meta default (from their docs) is `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">` so that shouldn’t be the problem. I use it on my sites too and don’t usually have any issues.

Comment: Hi @Richlewis that doesn't seem to be the issue. No change as you can see. Stuart I am a little dumbstruck! :)